# Normal random variable gives smooth density

Tags: probability

I am now reading a proof of Levy's Inversion Theorem and I have the following question.

> If $X$ is a random variable with distribution function $F$, Let $\xi$ be a $N(0,1)$ random variable which is independent of $X$, let $\epsilon >0$, put $X_{\epsilon}=X+\epsilon \xi$. **Then the addition of the independent Gaussian random variable gives $X_{\epsilon}$ a smooth density.**

Can someone explain why we can claim $X_{\epsilon}$ has a smooth density?

Answer (score 1):

If $\epsilon \xi$ has cdf $F$, we have for all real $y$
$$ \mathbb P(X+\epsilon \xi < y) = \mathbb E [ \mathbb P[X + \epsilon \xi < y \mid X]]
 = \mathbb E[F(y - X)] $$
Using dominated convergence,

$$ \dfrac{d}{dy} \mathbb E[F(y-X)] = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\mathbb E[F(y+h - X) - F(y-X)]}{h} = \mathbb E[F'(y-X)] $$
and since all derivatives of $F$ are bounded and smooth, we can repeat this arbitrarily often to get

$$ \dfrac{d^n}{dy^n} \mathbb E[F(y-X)]= \mathbb E[F^{(n)}(y-X)]$$